# Recursion in java (includes array)

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Hey I have a java code and want to know what it does.

```
public class HelloWorld{

public static int w(int []a, int start, int k)
{
    if (start==k) return start;
    else
    {
        int m = w(a, start, k-1);
        if(a[m] > a[k]) return m;
        else return k;
    }
}

 public static void main(String []args){
    int [] arr = {1,3,2,8,3,6,9};
    System.out.println(w(arr, 1, 5));
 } }
```

Output is `3`. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just walking through the code manually, as if _you_ were the computer, and writing down what each step does?

Comment: Maybe load it up and test it then? Or are you writing a test right now?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can be solved with debugger

Answer (score 1):

The code finds the index of the biggest element between given two indexes, `start` and `k`.

With the given input, between the indexes `1` and `5`, the subarray is `3,2,8,3,6`, and the biggest element among them is `8`, which has the index `3` in the original array.

Comment: Did you found it going through it yourself?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, I had a look into the code and to ran it in my mind. With a small input, it is possible the keep the previous states in mind and find out what it does.

Comment: Yea I guess. Found declaring an integer and giving a value as another recursive function very confusing

Comment: @IlanYashuk The problem is that you are going to find many problems like this in programming/computer science.

Comment: That's right. For this specific problem, you could look from this perspective: If you were to write the iterative version of this function, how would you do it? Then, how would you convert that into a recursive one?